# Unzip .zip file from Assets folder to Internal Storage (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

So the question is pretty simple. I'm using Xamarin.Android and I have a zip file in the Assets folder named "MyZipFile.zip", which I want extracted to the following path: `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);`

It sounds simple enough, but I cannot figure out how to read the Asset into memory through the `AssetManager` and then unzip it at the targeted location.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Did my answer not work for you?

Answer (score 3):

The Android Java framework includes a `Java.Util.Zip` package, so without adding any additional app libraries, I directly use it instead of using C# framework code, thus no bloat that linking can not remove.

So basically you are creating an asset stream and feeding that to a `ZipInputStream` and iterating over each `ZipEntry` in that zip stream to either create directories or files to your destination path.

#### UnZipAssets

```
public void UnZipAssets(string assetName, string destPath)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int byteCount;

    var destPathDir = new Java.IO.File(destPath);
    destPathDir.Mkdirs();

    using (var assetStream = Assets.Open(assetName, Android.Content.Res.Access.Streaming))
    using (var zipStream = new ZipInputStream(assetStream))
    {
        ZipEntry zipEntry;
        while ((zipEntry = zipStream.NextEntry) != null)
        {
            if (zipEntry.IsDirectory)
            {
                var zipDir = new Java.IO.File(Path.Combine(destPath, zipEntry.Name));
                zipDir.Mkdirs();
                continue;                                                 
            }

            // Note: This is deleting existing entries(!!!) for debug purposes only...
            #if DEBUG
            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(destPath, zipEntry.Name)))
                File.Delete(Path.Combine(destPath, zipEntry.Name));
            #endif

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(destPath, zipEntry.Name), FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                while ((byteCount = zipStream.Read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
                }
            }
            Log.Debug("UnZipAssets", zipEntry.Name);
            zipEntry.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
UnZipAssets("gameModLevels.zip", Path.Combine(Application.Context.CacheDir.AbsolutePath, "assets"));
```

Note: Even through the asset/zip steam is fast, depending upon number/size of the zip entries and the speed of the flash the entry is being written to, this should be done on a background thread as not to block UI thread and cause an ANR